# Compute Variance of Poisson Binomial-esque variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

**Disclaimer** I'm pretty inexperienced at statistics so I apologize if this is a simple question that I have made too complicated!

**Question** Suppose we have the following situation: there are $N$ discrete bins $1,\dots,N$. At a particular time $t=0$, each bin has some number $n_k$ of particles in it ($k=1,\dots,N$). At each discrete time step, for each $k=1,\dots,N$, every particle in bin $k$ undergoes a Bernoulli trial with success probability $p_k$ (note that $p_k\neq{p_j}$ for $j\neq{k}$ in general). If the trial is successful, the particle moves to bin $k+1$ (if $k=N$, the particle leaves the system). If the trial is unsuccessful, the particle is said to *expire*, and also leaves the system.

Let $E$ denote the number of particles which expire (*i.e.* do not reach bin $N$ and have a successful Bernoulli trial in bin $N$). I have the following estimate for the expected value of $E$:

$$ \mathbb{E}\big[E\ \big]=\sum_{t=1}^N\big[n_t\big(1-\prod_{k=t}^Np_k\big)\big] $$

My reasoning is: the quantity $\prod_{k=t}^Np_k$ is the probability that a particle which has made it to bin $t$ will make it out of the last bin without expiring. We then negate this quantity to get the probability that it *does* expire, multiply by the number of particles in the bin $t$, then sum over all bins.

1. Is the estimate for $\mathbb{E}\big[E\ \big]$ correct?
2. What is the variance of $E$? How can I compute it? I'm not sure what $\mathbb{E}\big[E^2\big]$ would be.
3. Is there a well-known distribution or something like that which describes this situation? It seems related to the **Poisson-Binomial** distribution, but I can't quite get my finger on it.

Thanks!

Comment: Your approach looks good. Let $X_{tu}$ be the indicator of the $u$-th particle in the $t$-th bin to expire, $u = 1, \ldots, n_t$, $t = 1, \ldots, N$. Then $\displaystyle X_{tu} \sim \text{Bernoulli}\left(1 - \prod_{k=t}^Np_k\right)$, and they are independent. And $\displaystyle E = \sum_{t=1}^N \sum_{u=1}^{n_t} X_{tu}$

Comment: Extremely helpful comments. So I compute the variance as: $\displaystyle\sigma^2=\sum_{t=1}^{N}\sum_{u=1}^{n_t}\left[\prod_{k=t}^{N}p_k\left(1-\prod_{k=t}^{N}p_k\right)\right]$